# sending hexadecimal values in c and check it for bit set

Tags: c, linux, sockets, hex

I am working on socket programming in Linux.Client is sending the below given hexadecimal values.I have to recieve the values on server side and check 8,9,10 and 11th hexadecimal values that which bits are set..
I am using following code but it's printing some weired output.
Please help me with this..

CLIENT:

```
void infostate(int sockfd,int confd)
{
char responsedata[]={0x7E,0x11,0x01,0xD0,0x00,0x4E,0x2F,0x0F,0x0F,0x70,0xFF,0xF5,0x25,0xF3,0x0D};
int rc;
rc=send(sockfd,responsedata,sizeof(responsedata),0);
if(rc<0)
{
    perror("error in sending\n");
    close(confd);
    close(sockfd);
    exit(-1);
}
else
printf("data successfully send\n");
}
```

SERVER

```
void identifycmd(char command[],int acceptsd,int sd)
{
     if(command[11]=='8' && command[12]=='3')
{
    char responsedata[14];
    rc=recv(acceptsd,responsedata,sizeof(responsedata),0);
    if(rc<0)
    {
        perror("error in recieving\n");
        close(acceptsd);
        close(sd);
        exit(-1);
    }
            printf("the response data is\n");
            for(i=0;i<sizeof(responsedata);i++)
            {
                    printf("%x",responsedata[i]);
             }
             printf("\n");


    checkretval(responsedata);
    processinfostate(responsedata);

}


}
void processinfostate(char responsedata[])
{   
char  z[8];int i,j;

unsigned char mask[]={128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1};
char x;j=9;
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
            x=responsedata[j];
    z[i]=(x & mask[i]);
    printf("%c",z[i]);
        j++

     }

}
```

Comment: This code won't even compile.

Comment: And what kind of "weird output" is it producing?

Comment: Why are you sending the data as characters? You could send it as shorts or longs and save bandwidth. Also makes the use of the data easier.

Comment: Can you please xplain this req with an example "check 8,9,10 and 11th hexadecimal values that which bits are set"

Comment: There was somw mistake in the previous code so i have edited the code.

Comment: I have to check individual bit of 0F,70,0F,F5 hexadecimal values whether it is 0 or 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one instead of your `processinfostate` function

```
void processinfostate(char responsedata[])
{   
 char  z[8];int i, j;
 int indexToCheck[4] = {8, 9, 10, 11};
 unsigned char x;

 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
    x=responsedata[indexToCheck[i]];
    printf(" %x ",x);  
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {  
        z[i] = ((x >> j) & 0x1);
        printf(" %x ",z[i]);  
    }
    printf("\n");
 }

}
```